# socket.io - multiple connections causing slow message emits to server

Tags: node.js, socket.io, engine.io

Note: When I delete "node_modules\uws\uws_win32_59.node" it works fine. uws is used by engine.io, which is used by socket.io.

I wrote a very basic app to demo the problem. In the below app, with 2 tabs of the index.html open in chrome, clicking "emit" emits the message from the client, but takes a significant, variable amount of time to reach the server. Anywhere from 2-15+ seconds. If I only have 1 index.html page open, it works fine, but once a second one is opened, I encounter the problem. If I delete the above uws_win32_59.node, it works fine with multiple connections.

**server.js**:

```
var io = require('socket.io')();

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('connection made');
    socket.on('number', function(num) {
        console.log(num + ' received on server');
        io.emit('number', num);
        console.log(num + ' emitted from server');
    });
});

io.listen(9001);
```

**index.html**:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.4/socket.io.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="emit">emit</button>

        <p id="nums"></p>

        <script>
                var socket = io('http://localhost:9001');    

                socket.on('number', function(num){
                        console.log(num + ' received on client');
                        document.getElementById('nums').innerHTML = num;
                    });      

                var num = 0;
                document.getElementById('emit').addEventListener('click', function(){                    
                    num++;
                    socket.emit('number', num);
                    console.log(num + ' emitted from client');
                });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

the default "npm install socket.io" installs that uws module mentioned above, which itself is used by engine.io.

run "node server" and open 2 instances of the index.html and click emit and notice the browser developer tools console logging and the node server console logging to recreate the issue.

EDIT: looks like there is an open issue with uws on windows os: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/3100

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need npm install socket.io@1.7.4. I think version 2.0 is significantly slower